# How to create trigger for nested tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create trigger for table3 to insert new row each I have basics information about triggers this is what I was trying to do however I got error execution interrupted

```
delimiter #
create trigger TABLE3_INSERT_TRIGGER  after insert on table2
for each row
begin
insert into table3 (tableZ_ID, table2_ID) values (new.tableZ_ID, new.table2_ID);
end#

delimiter ;
```

> ```
>         +------------+
>         | tableZero  |
>         +------------+
>         |tableZ_ID(PK|
>         +------------+
>         |tableZ_Name |
>         +------------+
>         |table1_ID(FK|
>         +------------+
>
>         +------------+
>         | table1     |
>         +------------+
>         |table1_ID(PK|
>         +------------+
>         |table1_Name |
>         +------------+
>
>         +------------+
>         | table2     |
>         +------------+
>         |table2(PK)  |
>         +------------+
>         |table1 (FK) |
>         +------------+
>         |table2Info  |
>         +------------+
>
>
>         +------------+
>         | table3     |
>         +------------+
>         |tableZ_ID(FK|
>         +------------+
>         |table2_ID(FK|
>         +------------+
> ```

Answer (score 0):

according to your table design there must be data available in tableZero otherwise it will give error related to reference key.

table 1 -> table 0

let me know if want more info

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger for table 2 you are referencing `new.tableZ_ID`, but there is not a `tableZ_ID` column in `table2`.

In order to get `tableZ_ID`, you have to join your `table2` values back to the table that contains the `tableZ_ID` column, which is `tableZero` based on your schema.  Given your FK relationships, in order to get from `table2` to `tableZero`, you have to go through `table1`.  The trigger would look something like this:

```
delimiter #
create trigger TABLE3_INSERT_TRIGGER  after insert on table2
for each row
begin
INSERT INTO table3 (tableZ_ID, table2_ID) 
SELECT t0.tableZ_ID, new.table2_ID
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN tableZero t0 on t1.table1_ID = t0.table1_ID
WHERE t1.table1_ID = new.table1_ID;
end#

delimiter ;
```